# "android" package name in styles v14

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I'm generating styles using Jeff Gilfelt’s [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). Browsing the `styles.xml` in the different `\values` folders I notice that in `\values-v14\styles.xml`, all the item names have the `android` package name in them. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#StyleExample

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the `android` prefix for support library compatibility when using the `AppCompat` library, but you do if you're styling the normal `ActionBar`, which in this case is API level 14+.

[Styling the `ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground)